# WPF image control does not update images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wpf-controls

I am working on a project that requires me to get bunch of images and display them as a video. Which means, I will update Image control of WPF 30 times a second. 
So far no luck.

```
BitmapImage img = BitmapToImageSource((Bitmap)image);

this.image_box.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    //this.image_box.Source.Freeze();
    this.image_box.Source = img;

});

BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memory.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();

        return bitmapimage;
    }
}
```

image_box is the image control (wpf).
So, I was expecting this code to update image and give an illusion of video being played. Whereas it does nothing. I see waiting cursor on the window.

**Edited ---- More Info ----**

I created a simple program to check if images can be changed in image control. But the results are same. I see waiting cursor and no image.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageSource s1;
            ImageSource s2;

            s1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"IMAGE_PATH", UriKind.Absolute));
            s2 = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"IMAGE_PATH", UriKind.Absolute));

            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (image.Source == s1)
                        image.Source = s2;
                    else
                        image.Source = s1;
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error");
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Your `image_box.Dispatcher.Invoke` call implies that `BitmapToImageSource` is called in a background thread. If that's the case you'll have to call `bitmapimage.Freeze()` after `bitmapimage.EndInit()` to make it cross-thread accessible. However, you should have got an InvalidOperationException. Otherwise your code should work.

Comment: @Clemens, " If that's the case you'll have to call bitmapimage.Freeze() after bitmapimage.EndInit() to make it cross-thread accessible." didn't help. And I am working in the main thread so far.

Comment: Then the Invoke call is redundant.

Comment: I tried without Invoke also, didn't work. I am just experimenting random stuff. Nothing seems to work. I don't understand why. I see no errors...

Comment: `image_box` is actually shown somewhere in your UI? And `image` is a valid `Bitmap`? From what you've shown here, your question can't be answered.

Comment: Yes image_box is shown on UI, and bitmap is a valid picture ( I checked it by saving it on hard disk).

Comment: Have you tried changing the `CacheOption`? But this is just a guess at this point.

Comment: "CacheOption" of what?

Comment: `bitmapimage.CacheOption` *must be* `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`, nothing else!

Comment: Yes, i tried to change it, nothing happened. Further more, I activated image_box_ImageFailed event, this too never got executed.

Comment: @Clemens, would it help, if I tell you that images i receive are from TCP socket in byte form, which later then are converted. As I said before, I save those images as files and I see them accurately received.

Comment: If `image` is a valid Bitmap, your conversion code should work. But why do you create a Bitmap at all, instead of directly decoding a BitmapImage from the byte array?

Comment: because the server application send me in Bitmap byte array.

Comment: A byte array isn't automatically a Bitmap. I guess the server either sends you an encoded bitmap frame, e.g. a PNG or JPEG, or a raw pixel buffer, in which case you'll have to know the width, height and pixel format of the resulting bitmap in advance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147452/discussion-between-jasim-khan-afridi-and-clemens).

Answer (score 0):

Although I knew this fact, but still made the same mistake.
We are not allowed to update GUI in a loop. If we want to do so, we need to create a separate thread.